# Always use the indirect object pronoun?

Tags: gramática

In the grammar book Im reading, on the chapter on pronouns, it states that the indirect object pronoun is always used even when the noun is stated. Then it shows a few examples.
(1) El artista mostró la pintura a los estudiantes. (The artist showed th painting to the students.)

In the above example, shouldnt it be it be:
El artista les mostró la pintura a los estudiantes?

In another example, Juan le da el libro. (Juan gives the book to Maria).  Why is le used in this case, but not les in the previous example?